# What is the correct notation for writing a function of a function for multiple variables?

Tags: functions, notation

Suppose that $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N)$ is a real function of $N$ variables and that $g(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_M)$ is a real function of $M$ potentially different variables.

If I want to input $g(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_M)$ in the $x_1$ position in $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N)$, what is the proper notation for this for a peer-reviewed journal article? Would it be $$f(g(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_M), x_2, \dots, x_N),$$
$$f(g, x_2, \dots, x_N),$$
or
$$f(g, x_2, \dots, x_N; y_1, y_2, \dots, y_M)\;?$$
My worry is that the first is too "notation-heavy," the second is compact however it does not present the variables with which $g$ is a function of, and the third is more exact but feels wrong nevertheless. I often see the first and second in peer-reviewed journal articles, but I am unsure which is the general convention.

Comment: I would prefer the first formula. If the values for the $y_{i}$'s are fixed or they will not play a role in future arguments, the second formula is OK. The third formula will be confusing. How come $f$ has an extra $M$ variables?

Comment: I agree with Jay, but also consider removing the arguments of g simply, if it is clear that the function g is indeed a function of those variables. Often inputs to functions are indeed functions of other variables etc, so don't get too hung up on this. Do not use the latter - it looks like y's are parameters in f.

Comment: The last notation is terrible. It relies on the name of the variables to indicate how to interpret. I don’t know of any notation for this, unfortunately. At heart, this is about the function $\phi_g:\mathbb R^{M}\times \mathbb R^{N-1}\to \mathbb R^{N},$ essentially what happens when $f$ is the identity function. Then for general $f,$ we’d have $f\circ \phi_g.$ But $\phi_g$ has no standard notation that I’ve seen, either. (Assuming everything is real numbers, of course.)

Comment: A vectorized notation like $$f(g(\mathbf y),\mathbf x)$$ is the most concise, and long as it is clear that $\mathbf x$ has dimension $N-1.$